# How to stop sending Heartbeat message of a DataNodeto to the NameNode?

Tags: java, hadoop, heartbeat

How to stop sending Heartbeat message of a DataNode or a specific DataNode to the NameNode? I know DataNode sends a Heartbeat every 3 seconds once and after 10 minutes, if DataNode will not send a message, it will be removed from the network.

Is there any way to intentional node deletion using interrupt in Heartbeat?
(I'm using Hadoop 2.9.0 and java)

Comment: How do you want to do this?  There are a bunch of options.  Is this a one-off? What OS are you doing this on?  Are you running on real hardware, VMs, containers or on a single host?  Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123655/emulating-network-disconnects-to-locally-test-distributed-app-partitioning

Comment: I have a cluster with 4 real nodes on 4 computers with linux os.

Comment: Are you okay with using `iptables` to restrict traffic?

Comment: I should do this with java programming. I want to remove a node middle of work.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do this only with Java.  But you'll need to block the traffic from `dfs.namenode.rpc-address` (and optionally `dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address` and `dfs.namenode.lifeline.rpc-address` if these are configured) from the datanode.